# String gets a weird form after calling a ndk c++ function from Android Java

Tags: java, android, c++, string, android-ndk

This is the function I call from Android:

```
String entityID = "414";
app.JoinConference(entityID);
```

And I have this code in my c++ jni files:

```
JNIEXPORT void Java_com_vidyo_vidyosample_VidyoSampleApplication_JoinConference(jstring eid)
{
FUNCTION_ENTRY;
LOGI("GuiOnOutEvent errorNOT JoinConference() enter\n");
VidyoClientPortalServiceJoinConferenceRequest createSchedRoomReq = {0};
createSchedRoomReq.typeRequest = VIDYO_CLIENT_PRIVATE_SOAP_JOIN_CONFERENCE;
LOGI("GuiOnOutEvent errorNOTJoinConference enter3: %s \n", eid);
//  createSchedRoomReq.entityID = eid;
strlcpy(&createSchedRoomReq.entityID, eid, sizeof(eid));
LOGI("errorNOTJoinConference request is:  %d pin %s + link: %d ", createSchedRoomReq.typeRequest,
     createSchedRoomReq.entityID, VIDYO_CLIENT_PRIVATE_IN_EVENT_VCSOAP);
LOGI("errorNOTJoinConference sizeof : %d", sizeof(VidyoClientPrivateSoapInEventCreateScheduledRoom));
VidyoClientSendEvent( VIDYO_CLIENT_PRIVATE_IN_EVENT_VCSOAP, &createSchedRoomReq, sizeof(VidyoClientPortalServiceJoinConferenceRequest));
LOGI("GuiOnOutEvent errorNOTJoinConference EXIT\n");
FUNCTION_EXIT;
}
```

What Am I doing wrong? The line with "enter3" which logs out the eid, logs out the following instead of "414":

```
01-24 18:04:29.310: I/VidyoMobile app/src/main/jni/ndkVidyoSample.c(12976): GuiOnOutEvent errorNOTJoinConference enter3: |9Ǵ
```

What should I use instead of jstring in the methods parameters for the ndk function? OR do I need to change it from both the android and ndk to some kind of char array?

Comment: A `jstring` is not a `char*`. You need to use `GetStringChars` or `GetStringUTFChars` to get the contents of the string. See the [JNI documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant directly pass `jstring eid` as argument to printf like function, you need to first get `const char*`from it, like:

```
const char *s = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, eid, 0);
```

use `s` as argument to LOGI, and then when `s` is no longer needed:

```
(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, eid, s);
```

Also why your jni function have no `JNIEnv *env` parameter? Static native methods signature should be:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
....... (JNIEnv *env, jclass type, jstring str);
```

and for non static:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
....... (JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jstring str);
```

with android studio support for jni code its now super easy, you write in java code your native function for example:

```
public native void test(String s);
```

then IDE marks it as red, you click alt+enter on it and choose to generate native function which looks as follows:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_test(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jstring s_) {
  const char *s = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, s_, 0);

  // TODO

  (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, s_, s);
}
```

Comment: I'll add then the "JNIEnv *env, jobject instance," before my jstring?
And ok, I get that you cannot print an jstring. and that's why I get |9Ǵ . But I get the same value for createSchedRoom.entityID . That means that it also sends that to the function?

Comment: `strlcpy(&createSchedRoomReq.entityID, eid, sizeof(eid));` is wrong for the same reason, you cannot copy directly using `eid` you need to first get `const char*` from `eid`, so it would look like: `strlcpy(&createSchedRoomReq.entityID, s, strlen(s));`

Comment: but I assume createSchedRoomReq.entityID is some char array, maybe its not?

Comment: char entityID[MAX_EID_SIZE];

Comment: It worked like this:
`const char *s = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, eid, 0);
 strlcpy(&createSchedRoomReq.entityID, s, strlen(s)+1);`
But what I don't understand, why if I would use strlen(s) like you did, I would only get "41" instead of "414" is s is "414"

Comment: @rosualin I was wrong above, strlcpy works differently - third parameter is the size of the entire buffer, so the correct code is: `strlcpy(createSchedRoomReq.entityID, s, sizeof(createSchedRoomReq.entityID));`